# What does iCloud sync do in Messages?

Tags: messages, data-synchronization, messages-in-icloud

What does iCloud sync in Messages do? I'd have thought that it was a way of ensuring that messages on one of my devises appear on the others, but that's not how it works. For example if I have Messages off for a bit on my Mac, none of the messages sent or received on my other devices ever show up in Messages on my Mac. So "sync" must be doing something else. What is that and what is accomplished by enabling enabling it? What would happen if I disabled it?

Comment: You're interpreting what it should do correctly, it must not be operating properly on your device.

Comment: In the Messages preferences pane, select the "iMesage" tab and make sure the account is enabled and it's synced to iCloud.  Click on the "Sync Now" button.  I've had Messages on my Mac "off" for about a week.  I opened it and all messages were there.  Try this to see if it gets you back in sync

Comment: @Allan Yeah I tried that. I'll try waiting. Apple seems religiously opposed to providing  sync status of any kind, which has really undermined the UX for their cloud stuff. It could be syncing for all I know.

Comment: The sync status appears in the lower left of main window, at the bottom of the messages list on macOS

Comment: Are your "other devices" (iPhones??) set to forward text messages to your Mac. And with Messages enabled in iCloud settings? Do messages sync between your "other devices"?

Comment: @Gilby Messages sync fine between my MacBook and iPhone (two devices) except for the ones that go missing on the Mac when Messages is not active on the Mac.

Comment: @Ezekiel I'm running Big Sur. What version shows status (I don't see it)?

Comment: @orome All versions that support iMessage in iCloud show the status. It doesn't appear when it's not doing anything